# OpenEdge ABL - write XML

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Is it possible to do this in Progress OpenEdge ABL?
I already have the code for Company = A.

> ```
> dataset dsOut:write-xml("FILE",dTempXmlFile,true,"UTF-8").
> ```

If Company = A then this is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <LoadNotification>
    <LoadID>10167</LoadID>
    <ShipmentTransferNumber>2320373</ShipmentTransferNumber>
  </LoadNotification>
```

else if Company = B then this is the xml  (notice an additional node appear)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <LoadNotification>
    <LoadID>10167</LoadID>
    <RetailID>AMZN</RetailID>
    <ShipmentTransferNumber>2320373</ShipmentTransferNumber>
  </LoadNotification>
```

I want to avoid self closing tag for company A..
I don't want to show `<RetailID/>` in company A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <LoadNotification>
    <LoadID>10167</LoadID>
    <RetailID/>
    <ShipmentTransferNumber>2320373</ShipmentTransferNumber>
  </LoadNotification>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [write-xml](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/pdsoe/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.openedge.pdt.langref.help/rfi1424920104068.html) method has a ninth parameter `omit-initial-values`. If you can ensure that your RetailID matches the initial value (or reset it) when company is A then it will be skipped in the output.

```
define temp-table tt
    field ii as int
    field cc as char initial ?
    .
define dataset ds for tt.
def var lcxml as longchar.

create tt. assign tt.ii = 1 tt.cc = 'one'.
create tt. assign tt.ii = 2. // no cc

dataset ds:write-xml( 'longchar', lcxml, true, 'utf-8', ?, ?, ?, ?, true ).

message string( lcxml ).
```

Watch it run on [ABL Dojo](https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=634723183fb02369b254a128), otherwise output here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ds xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tt>
    <ii>1</ii>
    <cc>one</cc>
  </tt>
  <tt>
    <ii>2</ii>
  </tt>
</ds>
```